# Python script not logging when run via "ssh -t"

Tags: python, bash, logging

I have logging set up in my python script to output to a file for error logging. This works fine when run from the device it is deployed on but when the script is run via ssh -t and exits with a sys.exit(0), nothing is logged.

Is anyone familiar with a workaround either in the bash script or in python?

Comment: How is the python script logging to the file? Are you checking for errors in opening (and writing to) the file? (I would assume you have to be since I think python throws an error if open fails.)

Comment: I'll have to check this. I don't actually have exception handling on the logging setup.